# How to get the survey's name in using workflow 2010

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, survey, reusable-workflow

I have created a simple workflow to send an email when users take the survey. I have been experimenting and I could not get the workflow to send email with name of the survey.

## Environment Information:

1. SharePoint 2013 Enterprise
2. Using SharePoint Designer 2013.
3. Created a reusable workflow using SharePoint 2010 workflow.

Comment: Are you using OOTB survey lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OOTB SharePoint doesn't gives us an option to get the List title in the SharePoint workflow. You can try any one of the below approach,

1. you could define a new variable and save the URL Path of the List within the newly created variable. After that just extract a substring at the position of the Listname.

For instance your URL Path to the List is:

'http://shppage/Lists/NameOfList/AllItems.aspx'

just get the substring after Lists/ up to until /AllItems

In this Case, copy Substring from 20 to 30(Into the Variable:ListName).

2. Create a new text column with a Default value of the list's Title. This will allow you to access the list title from the "Current Item" context within the workflow.
3. You can use this workflow action, to get the list name ,

https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=wfa